# Postgres : Get name value from json array using SELECT

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

In a column say **details** the values are stored as:

```
[{"id":"key1","name":"Concerts \u0026amp; Tour Dates"},{"id":"key2","name":"Nightlife \u0026amp; Singles"}]
```

Column Type: text

I need to get comma separated value for name using a single SELECT statement.Also need the amp sign.

Result:
[Concerts & Tour Dates,Nightlife & Singles]

Comment: While it probably possible to tackle this using SQL (look for JSON functions and FOREACH), it would probably be way easier and shorter to do it using any external programming language (e.g. `','.join([d['name'] for d in l])` would do most of the work in Python, and escaping the amp sign is pretty easy, too).

Comment: Nothing... @Craig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
select string_agg(d.e ->> 'name', ',')
from the_table, json_array_elements(that_text_column::json) as d(e);
```

To change `&amp;` to `&` use the replace function:

```
select string_agg(replace(d.e ->> 'name','&amp;', '&'), ',')
from the_table, json_array_elements(that_text_column::json) as d(e);
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/XAPDTC62018

Comment: Is it possible to use:: select id from the_table,json_array_elements(that_text_column::json) as d(e) where (string_agg(replace(d.e ->> 'name','&amp;', '&'), ',') && ('{test1,test2,test3}'))

Comment: @SyedAsadAbbasZaidi: what is that `&& ('{test1,test2,test3}'))` supposed to be?

Comment: && is to match array elements. What I'm trying to do is to match the string_agg value with my pre-defined array values. I knwo that I also need to do string_to_array after string_agg

Comment: `string_agg` returns a string, not an array, if you want an array you need `array_agg()`, but you are probably looking for the "contains" operator `@>`

Comment: Yes.. But over here there is a minor issue that we are not allowed to use aggregator function in the where clause

Comment: That's right, you need to use `having` for that: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP